# Codeigniter - Integrating tank_auth - issues loading libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

This is a pretty minor issue but it's bugging me - 
I am trying to integrate tank auth with my codeigniter site so I'm moving parts of the tank auth controller into my main page controller.

I usually load all libraries/models etc which are used throughout the controller as an array within the constructor e.g.

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation', 'security', 'tank_auth');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
}
```

This is for some reason producing a blank site (there is of course an index controller beneath this outputing content)

But the following code works fine:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('security');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
}
```

This isn't a mahor issue I know but I would appreciate any ideas as to why this doesnt work - surely they are doing the same thing - I am guessing that loading as an array is loading the tank auth library and security library simultaneously and the wrong one is loading first - is there a way to force load order when loading as an array?

Any input/thoughts much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `load()` to load multiple libraries, you have to pass in an array. [Reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html).

```
$this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'security', 'tank_auth'));
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that... been a long day